# The Usage of "Like Anything"

Tags: word-usage

I am a non-native English speaker from India. I would like to know the usage of "`Like anything`" when you want to emphasize something you want to say. For example, "`He beat him like anything`", "`She laughs at me like anything`". Do native speakers use this kind of language when they want to intensify their sentences? Out of all, is it correct to use "`Like anything`"? Can someone please shed some light on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have never heard that particular expression before and would advise against using it. See here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9478/like-anything-as-an-intensifier

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I have seen a lot of people using this expression particularly here in my part of the world.

Comment: Yes, it's just a general purpose intensifier, not uncommon in conversation in the UK. I'd be very surprised to see it written down, in anything but reported speech.

Comment: I think we may have a similar expression in Italian: "come niente" (literally: "like nothing")

Comment: This expression is also used in Australia, informally. It's for when you feel you need the intensity of a sharp metaphor or stock phrase, but can't think of one.

Comment: That being said, I don't mean it's simply a failure of thought. To say of a car that it _goes like anything_ is an accepted phrase in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have become familiar with the expression *like anything* as a general intensifier through Indian English, where it seems to be used very often - I have not heard it used regularly in any other dialect, which doesn't mean it is not used at all.

However, that does not mean I agree with Jonas' comment that *therefore* it should be avoided. As an intensifier, it is readily understood, also by people that have not heard it before, and it is certainly an established expression in what may be the fastest growing, and soon-to-be most-spoken, dialect of English.

I expect native speakers of Indian English to use this expression, as well as other particular expressions that adorn the Indian dialect of English.

It certainly causes less confusion to speakers of other dialect than the British use of *a rubber* - or for that matter, the Indian use of *bottom* to mean the lower part of one's clothing.

Comment: It's common enough in the UK

Comment: A very similar turn of phrase is (perhaps more AmE?) [_like nobody’s business_](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+nobody's+business).

Comment: I haven't heard of it much but "Like anything" is definitely something that people use more often..

Answer (score 3):

OED covers the usage under ***like*** sense B 1b...

> *In colloquial phrases denoting vigour or rapidity of action, as **like anything, like a shot, like fun, like blazes,** etc.*

They have citations going back to 1681 with ***like any thing***, but it's not until 1871 that we get the single-word version, in Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-glass*...

> [*They [the Walrus and the Carpenter] **wept like anything** to see
>
>    Such quantities of sand:
>
>    “If this were only cleared away,”
>
>    They said “it would be grand!”*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PUMiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&dq=%22They%20wept%20like%20anything%20to%20see%20Such%20quantities%20of%20sand%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JcXDU6HaGqmv7Abio4GoBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22They%20wept%20like%20anything%20to%20see%20Such%20quantities%20of%20sand%22&f=false)

In short, the usage is long-established, and has no particular associations with "Indian English" or any other regional dialect. But it remains rather colloquial/informal.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "single-word version". Is it "like anything" as opposed to "like any thing"?

Comment: @Rupe: Obviously. The original written form of [*anything*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anything) was two words *(**any thing**)*. Sometime in the two centuries between the 1680s and the 1880s the one-word form became more common. I simply wanted to make the point that the usage being asked about here predates that orthographic shift.

Answer (score 1):

I heard "like anything" from my father, whose family came from rural Iowa. I think I've also heard "like everything," but I may be mistaken. I used it myself just the other day (I grew up in southern California in the 1940s-50s, but I've always assumed it came from my midwestern roots.)